# TransitionGroup and CssTransition: Exit transition not applied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

I migrated from the old `CSSTransitionGroup` to the new [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) `CSSTransition` and `TransitionGroup`.

I'm creating (hacking) an overlay loader and I'm trying to apply animation to the overlay when it appears and disappears.

Specifically when I pass an `active=true` props to the `LoadingOverlayWrapper` then a new `CSSTransition` is added to the `TransitionGroup` (the `Fade`component) that wraps the overlay to show.

When `active=false` then the `CSSTransition` is removed from within the `TransitionGroup` (the direct child of `TransitionGroup`is `null`).

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
import React, {Children} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {CSSTransition, TransitionGroup} from 'react-transition-group'
import LoadingOverlay from "./LoadingOverlay";
import styles from './Overlay.sass';


const FirstChild = props => Children.toArray(props.children)[0] || null;

const Fade = (props) => (
  <CSSTransition
    {...props}
    timeout={500}
    classNames={{
      appear: styles.appear,
      appearActive: styles.appearActive,
      enter: styles.enter,
      enterActive: styles.enterActive,
      exit: styles.exit,
      exitActive: styles.exitActive
    }}
  >
    <FirstChild {...props} />
  </CSSTransition>
);


class LoadingOverlayWrapper extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {active} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <TransitionGroup>
          {
            active ?
            (
              <Fade key='transition_effect'>
                <LoadingOverlay key='the_dimmer' {...this.props} />
              </Fade>
            )
            :
            null
          }
        </TransitionGroup>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is the relevant sass file (imported as css module):

```
.enter, .appear
  opacity: 0.01

.appearActive, .enterActive
  opacity: 1
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in

.exit, .leave
  opacity: 0.01

.exitActive, .leaveActive
  opacity: 0
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in
```

The enter (or appear, not sure here) transition works.

The **problem** is that when I remove the `Fade` component, being replace by `null` then the exit transition is not applied (or not visible) but I get no error, everything else works as intended.

I'm not sure how to debug or proceed here given I have little experience with React TransitionGroup.

Comment: I am running into the exact same scenario with my limited knowledge of how TransitionGroup works.. were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: it's been a while but as I recall no, I did not find a solution :\

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with the same issue - the solution that worked for me is using the [childFactory](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group#TransitionGroup-prop-childFactory) prop on the `<TransitionGroup>` like so:

```
   <TransitionGroup
     childFactory={child => React.cloneElement(child)}
   >
      {
        active ?
        (
          <Fade key='transition_effect'>
            <LoadingOverlay key='the_dimmer' {...this.props} />
          </Fade>
        )
        :
        null
      }
    </TransitionGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

<CSSTransition
  in={toShow} // boolean value passed via state/props to either mount or unmount this component
  timeout={300}
  classNames='my-element' // IMP!
  unmountOnExit
>
  <ComponentToBeAnimated />
</CSSTransition>
```

NOTE: Make sure to apply below styles using the class property in CSS:

```
.my-element-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.my-element-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
.my-element-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.my-element-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition: opacity 300ms, transform 300ms;
}
```